# While used Thread.Sleep with pictureBox, Winform freezes

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, image, picturebox

I am working for a project where pictureBox used to show images from a directory one by one.

First I click start button. It calls a backgroundWorker which continuously run until I press stop button. Then inside backgroundWorker I called a timer with 500ms time interval. It calls a eventhandler method.

Inside evenhandler method first  I am taking the file name from the directory which is numerical and show in a pictureBox named "PicBox" and increment and then show the next image. I used a while loop that run whole process until I click stop button.

The problem is it starts after 500ms(timers interval) and shows all pictures in a high speed. I want to show them in a flow so that user can't realize that all is a combination of several images, but not at this speed.

I used Thread.Sleep() but it freezes the winform and I can't even click stop button.

**PictureBox** code is here:

```
if (_performReceiving)
{
    try
    {
        while (_performReceiving)
        {
            switch (firstNum)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    PicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path + "0" + firstNum + ".png");
                    this.PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    PicBox.Refresh();
                    firstNum++;
                    break;
                default:
                    PicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path + firstNum + ".png");
                    this.PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    PicBox.Refresh();
                    firstNum++;
                    break;
            } 
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MoveTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Is there any suggestion?

**EDIT:**(Visual view of code)

```
Form class
{
start_button clicked()
{
   //call backgroundWorker1
}

backgroundWorker1_DoWork()
{
   //create Timer1_handler
   //Timer1.Start()
}

Timer1_handler()
{
   //Process to get firstNames numeric value which passes to switch parameter

   :: This code posted on the main question ::
}
}
```

Comment: Dont use `Thread.Sleep`, its a blocking call, what are you trying to do

Comment: Don't block the gui thread?

Comment: Does this even compile? you can't fall through a `case` in c#

Comment: @Rotem - Yes you can, it joins all cases together. In this case, cases 0 - 9 all do the same code, found in case 9

Comment: Where is the call to `Thread.Sleep()`?

Comment: @Sayse My mistake, seems you can fall through only if there is no code in the `case`s.

Comment: I am not writing on the upper code.. I used that before every break;

Comment: @Rotem it will keep falling through even if there is code, it will keep executing until it hits a `break`

Comment: All code works great without any warning. I just want to show images slowly and smoothly.

Comment: @iabbott That is true only for c/c++. Try it in c#, it will give a `Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 1:') to another` compile error.

Comment: @NewBiL why you don't slow down your timer?

Comment: Timer's interval only works when it load first image .... and than a hoooooosh... @Alberto

Comment: @NewBiL can you please show us the code that fetches the images and where your timer is placed?

Comment: Hey is there any chance because you are starting your timer over and over in the `BackgroundWorker` that it tries to load images over and over? - Also why are you starting a timer, if you want to change the image at a specific point in the Thread then delegate the GUI to load a new image then by hardcoding it into the thread.

Comment: @Alberto Please take a look http://pastebin.com/6SySAqbB

Comment: @NewBiL Rather than having your timer's tick use a `While` to add all of the images, you should only do one per tick event, and then adjust the interval of the timer such that you're adding images at the rate that you want.  The timer's interval effectively becomes the time you would normally have been sleeping.

Comment: @Servy What about that if I use another timer after case and before break. And in this case how can I pass the firstNum value to that timer? Actually I also tried that but stuck on that passing value issue.

Comment: @NewBiL Without seeing your code it was hard for me to tell if you need a second time or not.  It may very well be the case that you do.  You can use a lambada when assigning the event handler to close over a value you want to pass.  It might look something like this: `int value = 0; otherTimer.Tick += (s,e) => TickHandler(value);`

Comment: @Servy I actually post this link on a previous comment. Here is my full code http://pastebin.com/6SySAqbB

Comment: @NewBiL I'm not going to go looking through a huge dump of your entire codebase, of which most isn't related.  If you can reduce your problem to a short but working example that can demonstrate your problem and doesn't include unrelated code, then it would be worth taking a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. No. No. No. No.

This is all wrong. Threading and WinForm, you must grok these things. WinForm runs on what is called the UI thread. This is the thread you must create controls on and the only thread that can access controls with (otherwise you can get deadlocks... or these days exceptions).

Secondly, background worker uses a background thread in doWork. This is not the UI thread and can be used to do lots of lovely processing. When you do updates with a background worker (I forget the exact API) it will marshal automatically to the UI thread for you. We good?

OKAY. Now here is your problem: System.Windows.Forms.Timer runs on the UI THREAD. It's a simple system that inserts items on the UI thread's queue at specific intervals.

So in your example it seems like you're calling a background thread that is then trying to base its work on a timer which lives in the UI thread. This is madness.

Use System.Threading.Timer instead OR throw away the BackgroundWorker altogether and just do this with one thread (the UI thread). As you're only loading 1 image at a time as long as the image is local you can probably get away with it without making the UI too unresponsive.

```
Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 5000;
    t.Tick += SomeEventHandlerThatLoadsAndDisplaysTheNextImage;
    t.Start();
}
```

or just use BackgroundWorker properly. If you do this you can add in .sleeps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // this is the UI thread
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }

        private BackgroundWorker worker;

        // this is the UI thread
        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        // this is the UI thread, the BackgroundWorker did the marshalling for you (Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke)    
        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Image) e.UserState;
        }
        // this is a background thread, don't touch the controls on this thread we use .ReportProgress (offered by the backgroundWorker) to marshal back to the UI thread.
        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (iNeedToKeepRotatingImages)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                var image = LoadAnImage(myState);
                worker.ReportProgress(0, image);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have some question. First, I have a start button. So `Load` will be inside button_start click. Is it? Could you please explain the line `pictureBox1.Image = (Image) e.UserState;` and `var image = LoadAnImage(myState);`. Where I will provide my image processing code?

Comment: No. Those are exercises for the reader to pursue. I feel like I've provided enough to get you going.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question. I am new in C#, that's why many things makes me little bit confusing. Whatever, hope this one works for me.

Comment: okay, just those though :D. UserState is a place where you can put information to easily share between threads. Here I put image in it in doWork. The line you queried is where I take that image back out. LoadAnImage is where you would load your image. The "myState" variable is just whatever you have in your program to track which image one is currently being viewed. HTH!